# How to bump up text size & other graphical elements system wide

Tags: macos, icon, resolution, text, display

On Mavericks, my monitor resolution is set to 1920 x 1080 @ 60Hz (1080p) on SMS24A350H.

Everything looks great. But I noticed small icons in Finder window with small text. That I adjusted with Finder view options globally. But I could not solve the problem of small fonts appearing in system dialogue windows such as in “Get info” window and System Menu bar etc. It is hard to read text there and icons looks smaller.

[image: safari:small text on tabs and other places]

[image: Small text on get info window]

[image: Small text on System Menu Bar]

In specific applications I can adjust zooming in contents area, like in Safari or Google Chrome but there also system wide objects like labels on tabs appear too small.

Screen zooming under system preferences is not a solution I want. I don’t want to trade off monitor resolution either.

Is there a way to get slightly zoomed everything system wide, which affects all applications and objects appearances?

Comment: did you check the sys pref accessibility options ?

Comment: Thanks but I have gone through it already, what I learnt is that it works to zoom a portion of screen. Some screen area may span out of monitor visibility after zooming. It is temporary and It reverts back with another key combination

Comment: you can zoom window in window or full screen

Answer (score 1):

Managed to try Quartz debug in my Mavericks. After enabling HiDPI display mode, I got this in display preferences.[image]

Noticed only 960 X 540 (HiDPI) is available. which **doubles** everything that appears on screen.

very nice and crisp looking font and icons are smooth but it is too big for the need. Just double.

Is there a way to get a resolution option with HiDPI for slightly smaller view size without compromising Graphics engine resolution. My monitor is Samsung 24' LED.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no good way to do this and no way to only increase the resolution slightly. If you download Quartz Composer from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/, you can use a HiDPI resolution, which completely doubles the size of everything on your display and uses higher-quality graphics, like the way a Retina MacBook Pro would work. With a 1080p display that would be like having a 960x540 display. If you click on the image below you can see how huge the text is.

[image: screenshot of HiDPI]

Comment: Thanks about this idea. I am learning about Quartz debug. supposed to provide multiple HiDPI options under display preferences. Does Quratz debugger need xcode to be completely installed all the time? xcode is itself a huge download and install.

Comment: @sunnyimran: No, it can be installed separately.